# Can I pull data off of a Moto 360 (smart watch) using ADB?

Tags: adb, bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

I am a *complete* beginner to the world of Android, but I am also an intrepid forensics examiner. I have been given the opportunity to conduct research into pulling data from certain wearables, namely Android watches. A colleague of mine suggested I examine the Moto 360 smart watch, but my initial research into the methods of conducting that examination has fallen flat.

I come to you enthusiasts with some very basic questions.

1. Can ADB (or another tool) extract valuable data from this specific smart watch? If so,       how?
2. If there are no available data extraction techniques at this time, should I shift my focus to another wearable?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have you tried this: http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2014/07/16/common-android-wear-tasks-for-developers/